# How to Create Excel Formula to Get pass or fail in final level exam?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are 6 Subjects, (A,B,C,D,E,F are columns)
A- Maths
B- Bio Science
C- Physics
D -Chemistry
E -English
F -Computer Science

all student's subject wise Passing score is 50,  Maths and Bio and physics Pass is compulsory and also from remain 3 subject any one subject should pass to get final level. how to create excel formula for that?

i tried IF Function but I don't know how to select random subject according to the condition

Comment: And() for 3, then or() for 1 from other 3.

Comment: Using the setup in Unais' screenshot: `=IF(AND(COUNTIF($B2:$D2,">=50")=3,COUNTIF($E2:$G2,">=50")>0),"Pass","Fail")` or more of the same
`=IF(COUNTIF($B2:$D2,">=50")/3+COUNTIF($E2:$G2,">=50")/1>=2,"Pass","Fail")`.

Answer (score 2):

Coming from Python, I noticed that you can translate the functions `all()` into `MIN()>=x`, and `any()` into `MAX()>=x`. Which yields this formula:

```
=IF((MIN(B2:D2)>=50) * (MAX(E2:G2)>=50), "Pass", "Fail")
```

If you are uncomfortable with the logical product, you can replace it with `AND()` of course.
Added benefit of this formula: if there are more than 3 columns to compare, the explicit one will get longer and longer whereas this one will just stay the same. And even if columns are non-sequential, `MAX()` and `MIN()` will still work, like in `MAX(B2:C2,F2)`.

Comment: Why the colon after C2?

Comment: sorry, that is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Formula used in H2

```
=IF(AND(AND(B2>=50,C2>=50,D2>=50),OR(E2>=50,F2>=50,G2>50)),"Pass","Fail")
```